# put searching box in the left side of search button when clicked button

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have code who expand searching box when the button clicked, but I want the search box in the left side of button when clicked

here my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#displayText").click(function() {
        $("#toggleText").toggleClass("focused");
    });
});
</script>
```

I wrote in jsfiddle u can modify overthere n help me please 
https://jsfiddle.net/ehd5n0tx/1/

Comment: if you expand your window wide enough, it is actually on the left of the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the form under the first div to bring the search bar on left when click on searched icon. I did not touch the inline-style but I would suggest to move those styles to your CSS file.

```
ul.filter {
display: inline;
list-style: none;
}
ul.filter li {
text-transform: uppercase;
margin-left: 40px;
display: inline;
}
#displayText{position:relative; top:-18px; cursor:pointer; float: right;}
#toggleText {
-webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
-moz-transition: all .25s ease;
transition: all .25s ease;
visibility: hidden;
opacity: 0;
}
#toggleText.focused {
visibility: visible;
opacity: 1;
display: inline;
}
```

And HTML is:

```
<div class="kanan-models-2" id="search-dekstop">
   <div id="toggleText">
      <form style="
         display: inline;
         margin: 0;
         padding: 0;
         ">
         <input type="text" name="" placeholder="search" style="
            width: 200px;
            height: 30px;
            border-radius: 0;
            ">
      </form>
   </div>
   <ul class="filter">
      <li><a href="#tab1">ALL</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab2">FEMALE</a></li>
      <li><a href="#male">MALE</a></li>
      <li><img src="https://image.freepik.com/icones-gratuites/sortir-en-plein-ecran_318-9919.jpg" width="20"></li>
      <li style="margin-right:-30px;">
      </li>
      <li>
         <a id="displayText"><img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/hawcons/32/698627-icon-111-search-128.png" width="20"></a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have placed the search box in a list item that is before the button you are clicking. This will force the search form to appear to the left of the button.

Here, look at your list items. I've re-arranged them:

```
<li>
    <a id="displayText"><img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/hawcons/32/698627-icon-111-search-128.png" width="20"></a>
</li>
<li style="margin-right:-30px;">
    <div id="toggleText">
        <form style="
            display: inline;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        ">
            <input type="text" name="" placeholder="search" style="
                width: 200px;
                height: 30px;
                border-radius: 0;
            ">
        </form>
    </div>
</li>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ehd5n0tx/2/

Also, you should try and get away from inline styling and use an external stylesheet. It's easier to maintain and read.